# Font Awesome CSS Content Code issue

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am editing a wordpress theme which uses Font Awesome CSS content codes. For some reason, some codes work and others don't.

this works:

```
.wpl_prp_show_detail_boxes_cont .rows.feature.single:after {
    content: "\f1b9";
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font: 16pt "wpl-front";
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #FFFFF;
    color: #29a9df;
    padding: 0 2px
}
```

but if I use CSS content code "\f00c" (check-mark) taken from this reference:

http://www.weisbergweb.com/FontAwesome-CSS-Values/#4

It just shows a blank square. What could be the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the Font Awesome font for this element (i.e. `font-family: 'FontAwesome';` as opposed to the current font, which may not be defined the same?

Comment: I think you're right! that did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly indicate that the elements should use the actual Font Awesome font as opposed to the current one, which likely doesn't have the same character definitions :

```
/* This will allow the character codes to correspond to the proper glyphs */
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

Your previous font "wpl-front" likely just didn't have valid glyphs for the values that Font Awesome uses, thus the empty character being displayed. You can see this from the definition within Font Awesome itself :

```
/* Definitions within Font Awesome */
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: I believe the right property here is `font-family`, not `font`.

Comment: I've corrected it. It was a typo, I should have just pasted from my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rion, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Rion Williams, Let me know the purpose of the "font: normal normal normal ", 3 times using of "normal"

Comment: Sure, this is the main difference between using `font-family` which just sets the font being used and `font` which can define all of the font-related properties. The above statement is the equivalent to setting `font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal;  font-stretch: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1; font-family: FontAwesome`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response!

Answer (score 1):

I see your font incorrect, should change it to FontAwesome.

```css
.wpl_prp_show_detail_boxes_cont .rows.feature.single:after {
    content: "\f1b9";
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #FFFFF;
    color: #29a9df;
    padding: 0 2px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Much appreciated.